# How to run a command against a specific context with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have multiple contexts and I want to be able to run commands against a context that I have access to but am not pointed to, while in another context.

How do I run a command, say `$ kubectl get pods` against context B while I'm currently pointed to context A?

Comment: If you find yourself switching clusters often, you mind like this tool https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`--context` is a global option for all kubectl commands. Simply run:

```
$ kubectl get pods --context <context_B>
```

For a list of all global kubectl options, run `$ kubectl options`